Substitute photos after and before by scaling
The service of solving problems of urban environment (graffiti, potholes etc.). I show a photo after renovation. On mouse over I show the photo before renovation. On mouse out I'd like to restore the photo after renovation. Animation should be scaling both times.
I have failed. My attempt:
index.php
    <?php
        <img alt='<?=$problem->name?>' 
             class='img-fluid' 
             src='uploads/<?=$problem->photoAfter?>' 
             data-before='uploads/<?=$problem->photoBefore?>' 
             data-after='uploads/<?=$problem->photoAfter?>' 
             onMouseOver='hover(this)' onMouseOut='back(this)'>
    
    <script>
        function hover(el){                                
            el.src = el.dataset.before;
            el.classList.remove("after");
            el.classList.add("before");
        }
    
    
        function back(el){
            el.src = el.dataset.after;
            el.classList.remove("before");
            el.classList.add("after");     
        }
    </script>

site.css
    .before {
        animation: scaling 1500ms;    
      }
      
      .after {
        animation: scaling 1500ms;
      }
    
      @keyframes scaling {
        0% { transform: scale(0); }    
        100% { transform: scale(1);}
      }

This code doesn't work. Animation on mouse over works but it scales first and then substitutes the photo. And animation works only once. On mouse out it just substitutes the photo.
What can I try next?

Why not just stack them and use opacity to hide/show the top one in hover?

Regardless, questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself preferably in a Stack Snippet using the <> icon.  See How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example

@Paulie_D, could you publish a solution?

Like this - https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/KKjVEGZ ??

@Paulie_D, no, it's not what I meant. I need an animation effect. Namely scaling.

So use a scale instead... the opacity was just an example. The point was to show that you don't need to change src or pop images in/out. Just stack them and do whatever animation/transition you want on hover of the parent. - https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/BagjbbW

@Paulie_D, how come that you don't need to change src? Two photos. Different photos. And I can't imagine how I can transmit your code into what is needed.

There are two photos, they are just stacked one on top of the other.

@Paulie_D, I can't cope with that. Could you write the solution? Animation by scaling. Two different photos. Without any hue rutation.

@Kifsif what part exactly of the amazing EXAMPLE Paulie_D gave you is not clear? For what you're after there's no need for JS at all. use CSS :hover on a wrapper that has two overlapping images. Transition and scale the overlaying one. Also, by using CSS you would see the flash of content (image loading due to changing src)...

Just use the scale change on the :hover state:


.before-after {
  display: inline-flex;
  position: relative;
  img {
    transition: scale .4s;
    &:last-child {
      position: absolute;
      left: 0;
      top: 0;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      scale: 0;
      object-fit: cover;
    }
  }
  &:hover {
    img {
      &:first-child {
        scale: 0;
      }
      &:last-child {
        scale: 1;
      }
    }
  }
}
<div class="before-after">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1/200/300" alt="">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/2/200/300" alt="">
</div>



